# Parsing JSON in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, json

I have the following JSOn I need to parse:

```
{"items":[{"dict":"es","words":[{"word":"car","id":"3487"},{"word":"dog","id":"443"},{"word":"plane","id":"1171"}]},{"dict":"fr","words":[{"word":"house","id":"134"}]}]}
```

Using JavaScriptSerializer, how could I iterate first through each dict and then retrieve the id of each word?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: There are various JSon (de)serializers out there, you shouldn't have any trouble finding one...

Comment: Do you have any model that will hold this for deserialization?

Comment: @scheien I don't know where to start besides making my own parser. I know how to do this in PHP but I'm not that familiar with ASP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make anonymouse type,  acording your json, for example:

```
var result = new[] {new {action = "", value = false}}; // put your item structure here
var list   = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(myJson, result.GetType());
```

then you might want to itterate through. For example:

```
foreach (dynamic val in  ((dynamic) list)) { ...
```

Comment: How can I set the item structure in result ?

Comment: var result = new[] { new { dict = new  KeyValuePair<string, List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>>()}};